# Is there the ability to unit test a MaterialSearchBar on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-studio, searchbar

I've been unit testing my code and have been struggling to find a way to unit test a MaterialSearchBar on Android Studio from the `implementation 'com.github.mancj:MaterialSearchBar:+'` package.

I have attempted to unit test it by typing

```
@Test
public void searchForTony() {
    onView(withId(R.id.search_bar)).perform(click()).perform(typeText("Tony"));
}
```

But this does not seem to work, this is similar to the way I unit tested my EditText fields, can I please have some guidance on how to approach this?

Thanks

Comment: Its a UI test not a unit test

Comment: @karandhillon Have you any guidance to give me or do you wanna find any other faults in my wording?

Comment: There is no need to be mean. It is our job to make sure we are using correct semantics. Be professional.